# .NET assembly cannot be found in debugger if only registered into HKCU

Tags: .net, registry, .net-assembly, regasm

We have a COM-visible .NET assembly. This assembly is registered via 'per-user COM registration' by adding the registry entries into HKCU with admin privilege. The assembly is registered successfully and the COM object can be instantiated without any problem for users.

However, in debugger, like Visual Studio 2010, if I want to CoCreateInstance() one of the COM objects in the assembly, error code 0x80040154 which is 'Class not registered' returned. This hasn't happened when we used "regasm.exe /codebase *.dll" before. I checked that regasm.exe adds registry entries to HKLM. Here are my questions:

1. Debugger, Visual Studio 2010 in my case, only finds registry from HKLM instead of looking up in HKCU?
2. Is that true that regasm.exe registers assembly only into HKLM?

Thanks a lot for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

> by adding the registry entries into HKCU with admin privilege.

Using HKCU is brittle.  There's only one scenario where this can work properly, the admin privilege must have been obtained by the **exact same** user account that runs the program.  That can only happen when you've obtained UAC elevation, typically by running cmd.exe with the "Run as Administrator" option.

If you gained admin privilege with a different account then the keys are written to a *different* HKCU.  In other words, a different sub-key of HKEY_USERS.

1) And then your *program* that can't find the keys.  The debugger is not involved.

2) Which is why Regasm.exe only supports writing HKLM and doesn't have an option to write to HKCU.  Avoids the support calls.

Comment: Thank you @Hans. In all the scenarios, I am the only user and I have admin privilege. 
1) My program was run in VS2010 which has the admin privilege. I thought no matter where the assembly is registered, my program should look up in HKCR that I checked the ProgID is there.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: Not sure what you want me to agree with.  If this is just for private use and you have admin privileges then it makes no sense at all to use HKCU.

Comment: :) I wanted to know if you agree with me that HKCR is the hive that my program looks for the assembly's registry entry.

Comment: HKCR is a synthetic hive that's created by merging HKCU and HKLM.  It only exists for appcompat with old 16-bit code.  The exact rules on how that merge is done got very convoluted in 64-bit Windows.  COM doesn't use it, it always looks in HKCU and HKLM.  Easy to see when you use SysInternals' Process Monitor utility, the one you always want to use when you have registry lookup problems.

Comment: I just found out that if the assembly is registered into HKCU, my program can instantiate instance of COM object in the assembly when my program running **W/O** admin privilege. On the other hand, if I want my program to run in debugger, VS2010 which runs as admin, 'Class not registered' is got. So, HKCU is for non-admin users, this is what I didn't know.